# Complement of countable dense totally disconnected?

Tags: general-topology, real-numbers, connectedness

$A\subseteq \mathbb R^2$ and $X=\mathbb R^2\backslash A$ are both equipped with subspace topology inherited from $\mathbb R^2.$ If $A$ is countable and dense, does that imply that necessarily $X$ is totally disconnected $?$

If I take $A=\mathbb Q\times \mathbb Q$ then $A$ is countable dense and the complement $X=\mathbb Q^c\times \mathbb Q^c$ is totally disconnected. But is this always true I mean if I take any arbitrary $A$ from $\mathbb R^2$ qwill this hold as a result $?$

Comment: The complement of $\mathbb{Q}\times \mathbb{Q}$ is $\mathbb{Q}^c \times \mathbb{R}\cup \mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{Q}^c$, it is path-connected.

Comment: @DanielFischer: So the *example* I thought I'd found is actually a counter-example.

Answer (score 1):

The complement of $A$ is **not** totally disconnected - your equation $$(C\times C)^c=(C^c)\times (C^c)$$ is incorrect (e.g. the point $(\pi, 7)$ is in $A^c$ but not in $\mathbb{Q}^c\times \mathbb{Q}^c$). Indeed, the complement of $A$ is connected, as is any co-countable subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Can you please provide a reference that co-countable subsets of $\mathbb{R}^k$ are connected? Are they also path connected?

Comment: Ah, it is easy to see for connectedness!

Comment: @PaulFrost It's sufficiently elementary that I don't know a reference - just construct "lots of disjoint paths" and say "pigeonhole." For example, given points $p,q,r\in\mathbb{R}^k$ let $l_r(p,q)$ be the path from $p$ to $q$ gotten by going from $p$ to $r$ in a straight line and then from $r$ to $q$ in a straight line. Note that if $r_1,r_2$ are each equidistant from $p$ and $q$ we have $l_{r_1}(p,q)\cap l_{r_2}(p,q)=\{p,q\}$, and there are uncountably many such $r$ for any $p, q$. So given a countable $X$ not containing $p$ or $q$, we can always find $r$ such that $l_r(p,q)\cap X=\emptyset$.

Comment: Thank you very much! I asked because I wanted to answer https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2722227, but perhaps you should do that because it is your argument.